# Where can I find downloaded application from terminal installation in Ubuntu kernel?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, nautilus

I'm completely new to try Ubuntu 18.04.2, and I installed text editor Atom via Ubuntu terminal `sudo snap install atom --classic`.

I could see the Atom application in the dash and run it, but I can't find Atom in the directory "**/usr/share/applications**", which I needed it to be in there to create a shortcut on my desktop.

Is this happening because I downloaded Atom through terminal command instead of actually downloading the file to my desktop?

Comment: Please do not use the snap Atom, it is not officially supported and unofficial Atom builds often have mismatched components.

Instead, read the [Installing Atom](https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/#platform-linux) section of the flight manual, and set up the PPA. Then just run `sudo apt install atom`.

Comment: Oh, so is it not good to use snap to download any type of applications? or is it just Atom that is not good to download via snap?

Comment: I don’t have an opinion on Snap, but it’s important to know it is not provided or supported by the Atom team, and any issues you encounter will be dismissed until you verify them on an officially supported distribution. Some programs might have official Snap support, but Atom is not one of them.

Comment: I guess I'll have to delete the downloaded Atom to install it correctly again.